# How to use Multi languages work in next js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I want to know that can we use "multi language" library/module in nextjs for dynamic website ? in other words for example if admin "add" new blogs from "admin panel" then that blog details should display in other different languages also ? if yes then how can we do this ?

Comment: look at these two links [intl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-intl) , [localise](https://lokalise.com/)

Comment: For a blog, I would use a headless CMS to store the data to create the content in different languages. Then, I'll retrieve data and render the blog posts based on the selected languages in the user interface. Does that make sense for you?

Comment: @HaiHuynhNgoc it means for example i am going to add any blog then in backend "blog content" will store in "different languages" then we can fetch "blog content" according to "selected language", am i right ?

Comment: @RitikaVerma Exactly, you got it.

Comment: @HaiHuynhNgoc is this only option we have ? i mean can we do this without saving different "blog content" ? is this possible that if we store data in "english" language but in front end we can translate in any language (with use of any module/library) ?

Comment: Personally, I think it's not a clever way to achieve your goal. However, you may consider DeepL to translate your content automatically. If you want to handle the translations manually, you would need to use `next-i18next`. Check this out at  https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next